# Python: properly iterating through a dictionary of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, for-loop

Given the following `numpy` arrays:

```
import numpy
a=numpy.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
b=numpy.array([[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]])
c=numpy.array([[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]])
```

and this dictionary containing them all:

```
mydict={0:a,1:b,2:c}
```

What is the most efficient way of iterating through `mydict` so to compute the average numpy array that has `(1+2+3)/3=2` as values?

My attempt fails as I am giving it too many values to unpack. It is also extremely inefficient as it has an `O(n^3)` time complexity:

```
aver=numpy.empty([a.shape[0],a.shape[1]])

for c,v in mydict.values():
    for i in range(0,a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,a.shape[1]):
            aver[i][j]=mydict[c][i][j] #<-too many values to unpack
```

The final result should be:

```
In[17]: aver
Out[17]: 
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.]])
```

**EDIT**

I am not looking for an average value for each numpy array. I am looking for an average value *for each element* of my colleciton of numpy arrays. This is a minimal example, but the real thing I am working on has over 120,000 elements per array, and for the same position the values change from array to array.

Comment: `for c,v in mydict.values():` should be `for c,v in mydict.items():`

Comment: @JamesR good eye on that one :)

Comment: I think you just want something like `arr.mean(axis=1)`

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? What would be your output? Why are these arrays in a dictionary?

Comment: It's a long story. Climate data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this harder than it needs to be.  Either sum them and divide by the number of terms:

```
In [42]: v = mydict.values()

In [43]: sum(v) / len(v)
Out[43]: 
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.]])
```

Or stack them into one big array -- which it sounds like is the format they probably should have been in to start with -- and take the mean over the stacked axis:

```
In [44]: np.array(list(v)).mean(axis=0)
Out[44]: 
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.]])
```

Comment: Your first answer is giving me an error. `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict_values' and 'int'`

Comment: @kmario23: that error message says that the left hand operand is a dict_values instance.  But the result of `sum(v)` shouldn't be a dict_values object here, so I'm not sure what you're doing.

Comment: I'm trying to do these two steps:  `v = mydict.values()`  followed by `sum(v) / len(v)` with `mydict` as OP defines. Actually, `sum(v)` returns a type `dict_values`

Comment: @kmario23: oh, you probably did something dangerous like `from numpy import *` or something (or are operating in some environment which does the same).  If you use `numpy.sum` instead of `sum`, it'll give you that error.

Comment: Oh yes. But, I was using ipython with pylab backend. But, this is kinda crazy. Maybe it's better to add this info to the answer.

Comment: @kmario23: your difficulties have nothing to do with this question or answer, but about the fact you're using a broken environment.  We'd have to update half of the questions on SO which use `sum` or `any` or `all` or `min` or `max` or any of the builtin functions which a star import from numpy will override with a different version.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be using a `dict` of `numpy.array`s. Just use a multi-dimensional array:

```
>>> bigarray  = numpy.array([arr.tolist() for arr in mydict.values()])
>>> bigarray
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]]])
>>> bigarray.mean(axis=0)
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.]])
>>>
```

You should modify your code to not even work with a `dict`. Especially not a `dict` with integer keys...